# Getting status code out of WebResponse

Tags: powershell

What Im doing wrong?

```
$html = invoke-webrequest "http://google.com.au"
if ($html.statuscode = 200) {
          write.host "website up"
    }
    else {
          write.host "website down"
    }
```

im getting error statuscode is a readonly property

Thanks guys

Comment: Change `=` to `-eq` in the test; equals is for assigning values to variables like the first line, -eq is for comparing two things like the second line.

Comment: Thanks very much, that worked.